# Three players mixed strategy nash equilibrium problem

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, evolutionary-game-theory

[image: The table above represents payoff for three players game accordingly. The probability for z1 is z and z2 is (1-z), r1 is r and r2 is (1-r) meanwhile for p1 is p and p2 is (1-p).]

The table above represents payoff for three players game accordingly. The probability for z1 is z and z2 is (1-z), r1 is r and r2 is (1-r) meanwhile for p1 is p and p2 is (1-p).

**Firstly**, I would like to know whether the solution of mixed strategy for three players game is possible for my payoff matrix?

**Secondly**, I have extracted the mixed Nash equilibrium strategy as follows by using payoff value from player  Z:

**if player $P$ plays,**

$p_{1} = $50(z)(r)+0(z)(1-r)+100(1-z)(r)+50(1-r)(1-z)$

$p_{2} = $0(z)(r)+0(z)(1-r)+50(1-z)(r)+50(1-r)(1-z)$

Then equate $p1=p2$

$50(z)(r)+50(1-z)(r)=0$

**if player $R$ plays,(note: the payoff value of Z is read vertically)**

$r_{1} = $50(z)(p)+100(1-z)(p)+0(z)(1-p)+50(1-z)(1-p)$

$r_{2} = $0(z)(p)+50(1-z)(p)+0(z)(1-p)+50(1-z)(1-p)$

Then equate $r1=r2$

$50(z)(p)+50(1-z)(p)=0$

which after I have solved the equation $p = 0$

**if player $Z$ plays,(note: the payoff value of Z is read horizontally)**

$z_{1} = $50(r)(p)+0(1-r)(p)+0(r)(1-p)+0(1-r)(1-p)$

$z_{2} = $100(r)(p)+50(1-r)(p)+50(r)(1-p)+50(1-r)(1-p)$

Then equate $z1=z2$

$-50(r)(p)-50(1-r)(p)-50(r)(1-p)-50(1-r)(1-p)= 0$

which after I have solved the equation $-50=0$

Hence, I realized that it is impossible to solve for probability of p,z and r.
I want to know whether the equations are correctly performed or not for all players?

**Thirdly**, is there any other method that will be able to solve for the probability of p,z, and r.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). The first few terms are typeset for you.

Comment: It's not at all clear (not to me, anyway) which of the three payoffs given in the tables is distributed to which player.

Comment: Thank for the comments, I have edited it as to give a better view of the problem which I have encountered. Basically, I was not taught how to properly calculate the probability from the payoff matrix. All games theory aspects I learned through reading multiples journal. Hence, if you all have the solution for that problem, I would personally be blessed. Thank you for your help.